# Admob difference between SMART_BANNER and BANNER

Tags: android, admob

I have noticed that the SMART_BANNER is much better than BANNER, looks much better. But I fear that this change will affect on stats like CTR etc. Is the click on BANNER more expensive than click on SMART_BANNER  by user? This question may be stupid, but I want to make sure of this.

Answer (score 1):

I think smart banner is introduced to make add look more attractive and supportive to all screen resolution's of device. It can detect the screen orientation of device and always set the add on the center.

All the other factor are same as the old.

You can find more info here and most mediation ad networks do not yet support Smart Banners.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/smart-banners

Answer (score 0):

On my phone the landscape SMART_BANNER doesn't seem that attractive.  It is full screen but only 40 pixels tall, and no graphics (at least none that I've ever seen).

My next program will use BANNER for phones and SMART_BANNER for tablets.  I hope that's possible and doesn't violate the ToS.